# El listener selectedTextProperty de un campo de texto provoca error

Tags: javafx

Tengo un campo de texto con un listener que controla cada vez que selecciono una parte del texto que contiene. Por ejemplo, en la situación siguiente funciona todo correctamente cuando después de seleccionar los dos dígitos de la izquierda los sustituyo por un 5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando selecciono los dos dígitos de la derecha me aparece un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   3

El código es este:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectedText extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField campoTexto = new TextField();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(campoTexto);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 100, 100);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        campoTexto.selectedTextProperty().addListener((final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov,
                final String selectiónAnterior, final String selecciónActual) -> {
                    System.out.println ("Selección Actual: " + selecciónActual); 
                });
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Este comportamiento es provocado por un error interno de Java que aún no ha sido corregido. De momento prueba a modificar tu código utilizando otras propiedades como textProperty() y getSelection(). Echa un vistazo a esta pregunta en inglés de stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654002/exception-while-deleting-selected-text-in-javafx-textarea/33654478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto se debe a un bug en la API JavaFX, mientras no sea corregido puedes usar la propiedad selectionProperty para monitorear el cambio en la selección del campo de texto, en el Listener verificas si la selección es válida, obtienes el texto seleccionado usando el método getSelectedText.

```
campoTexto.selectionProperty().addListener((listener) ->  {
    if(!campoTexto.getSelectedText().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("sr: " + campoTexto.getSelectedText());
    }
});
```